# C++ Splitting a string into strings and ints

Tags: c++

If I have a line of input string from `std::cin` which consists of strings and ints separated by whitespaces. What is the most effective way to get them separated and stored?

e.g:

```
input: "Move 1 to 2" 
variables for storing: 
string a, b; 
int orig, dest;
```

**Edit:**

I have applied the following code as suggested. However, when I input "move 9 onto 1", it seems that only the word "move" is properly stored in the vector strs.

```
    string command;
    cin >> command;
    vector<int> ints;
    vector<string> strs;

    string strval;
    int intval;
    stringstream test;
    test.str(command);
    while(true) {
        if(test.eof())
            break;

        if(test >> strval) {
            strs.push_back(strval);
        }
        else if(test >> intval) {
            ints.push_back(intval);
        }
        else {
            cout << "error!" << endl;
        }
    }
```

**Problem Solved:** 

use

```
getline(cin, command);
```

instead of

```
cin >> command;
```

Comment: Are they alternating, or the order is not known?

Comment: Use a `stringstream`.

Comment: Look into stringstream with a delimiter

Comment: You can just read with `operator<<` using a string reference and a int reference. (assuming you know the type of data to expect)

Comment: @maditya they are alternating. Eg "Move 1 to 2"

Comment: Divide and conquer with a string stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume the order of ints and strings is unknown. You can exploit the conversion of `cin` to bool to decide whether you have detected an int or not.

Basically, `(cin >> intValue)` (where `intValue` is an `int`) is an expression which returns `true` if the next few characters constitute a valid number that can fit into an `int`, and `false` otherwise. Same principle applies for other types such as `string`. These can be used in if-statements such as

```
int intValue;
if (cin >> intValue) {  //evaluates to true or false
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```

You can use this with a while-loop to parse your whole input, like so:

```
vector<int> ints; //container to store ints
vector<string> strings; //container to store ints

while(true) {

  int intValue;
  string stringValue;
  if(cin.eof())  //exit the loop when the end of the input is reached
    break;

  if(cin >> intValue) {  //if this is true, then an int was successfully read into intValue
    ints.push_back(intValue);
  } else if (cin >> stringValue) { //if this is true, int could not be read but string was successfully read
    strings.push_back(stringValue);
  } else {
    cout << "Error: unknown value read in, not recognized as int or string" << endl;
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

### Edit:

I just read that you already have the line as a string. The same solution above will work, just use stringstream instead of cin:

```
string line; //the line that you already have, initialized elsewhere

stringstream ss(line.str()); //convert the line to a stringstream, treat it similar to cin
vector<int> ints;  //container to store ints
vector<string> strings;  //container to store strings

while(true) {

  int intValue;
  string stringValue;
  if(ss.eof())
    break;

  if(ss >> intValue) {
    ints.push_back(intValue);
  } else if (ss >> stringValue) {
    strings.push_back(stringValue);
  } else {
    cout << "Error: unknown value read in, not recognized as int or string" << endl;
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```

In your example, which was the line `Move 1 to 2`, The vector will contain `1` and `2`, and the vector will contain `Move` and `to`.

Comment: what if I have a std::cin to read one line and then separate them out? Is istringstream applicable here?

Comment: @Ra1nWarden Yeah I just saw that part of your question. You can use istringstream, stringstream etc. pretty much the same way, just convert your `string` which contains the line into a `stringstream` using the `stringstream::str()` function. I've edited my answer to include this solution.

Comment: sorry, I do not know what I did wrong but it seems that I only get the first element from the string.

Comment: @Ra1nWarden I'm looking into it, seems like I slightly messed up the initialization of the stringstream. Will let you know shortly. Meanwhile, is it possible that the way you got the line was not correct? Could you please verify that the `string` object that contains the line actually contains the whole line? You can do `object.size()` to check how many characters there are.

Comment: Haha, you are right! I used getline(cin, command); instead of cin >> command; Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for ***parsing*** text.

Your "input grammar" is... underspecified, but here goes with a Parser framework like e.g. Boost Spirit:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Command { std::string name; int a, b; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Command, (std::string, name)(int,a)(int,b))

int main()
{
    const std::string input("Move 2 to 4");

    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    Command parsed; 

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,
           qi::string("Move")     >> qi::int_ >> "to"   >> qi::int_
         | qi::string("Multiply") >> qi::int_ >> "by"   >> qi::int_
         | qi::string("Subtract") >> qi::int_ >> "from" >> qi::int_
         , qi::space, parsed);

    if (ok)   
    {
        std::cout << "parse success\n";
        std::cout << "parsed: '" << parsed.name << "' with (" << parsed.a << ", " << parsed.b << ")" << "\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
parse success
parsed: 'Move' with (2, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am having problem with understanding your code. (I am quite new to this.) Could you please help me simplify this? Like I have a few lines of commands "move 1 to 2" "move 3 to 1" etc. I want to parse each line into strings for the words "move", "to" and ints for values "1", "2" etc.

Comment: @Ra1nWarden I was afraid you'd say that :) I already simplified this way beyond usable minimum. My main concern here is that you're asking an [XY-question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The most useful bit of my answer will probably be the first line: **you're looking for "parsing text"**. Take your time to experiment and learn about the real requirements _further down the road_. It'll become clearer. As of now, I don't think I can help you further (without a much  clearer _goal_)